# Raise and lower QTreeWidgetItem in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreewidget

Question says it all how do you raise and lower [change the positions of ] QTreeWidgetItems in a QtreeWidget ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you would need to use model object to be able to manipulate items positions (if this what you want to do). Please check an example below; it moves the first item of the abstract model to the bottom.

```
QAbstractItemModel* model = your_tree_view->model();

QModelIndex index0 = model->index(0, 0);
QMap<int, QVariant> data = model->itemData(index0);
// check siblings of the item; should be restored later
model->removeRow(0);

int rowCount = model->rowCount();
model->insertRow(rowCount);
QModelIndex index1 = model->index(rowCount, 0);
model->setItemData(index1, data);
```

once item moved in the model your treeview widget should update itself accordingly

in case you need to change the size of the item shown by your treeview install an [item delegate](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and override its [sizeHint](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) method

hope this helps, regards

Comment: LOL, 
1. get the model of the treeview.
2. get the model index of the row / column .
3. use the index to get the data .
4. remove it.
5. insert a blank row .
6. get the index of the blank row.
7. set the data of the blank row using the index.

Back on Gtk+ the api on a treestore was like insert(), move_after(),move_before(),swap(), etc. This qt stuff is completley unintuitive, why people say its better than Gtk+ i'll never know. Once again thanks Serge.

Comment: @spearfire: part of this is using the widget variants of the model/view setup in Qt.  If you were doing a model yourself, you would just change where the data is in the model (and emit the appropriate signals), and the UI would update itself to match.

Comment: Your right, simply swapping data and children is far more effective

Answer (score 3):

I found serge's solution to be quite complicated as well for a simple move up / move down.
There's actually a quite easier solution to this issue since you're using QTreeWidget :

```
QTreeWidgetItem* item = your_qtreewidget->currentItem();
int              row  = your_qtreewidget->currentIndex().row();

if (item && row > 0)
{
    your_qtreewidget->takeTopLevelItem(row);
    your_qtreewidget->insertTopLevelItem(row - 1, item);
    your_qtreewidget->setCurrentItem(item);
}
```

Here you have a code to move an item up. From this you should be able to find how to move it down in no time :) !